# Sonar exclusions are not working which mentioned in sonar-project.properties file

Tags: spring-boot, maven, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

I'm using GitLab CI/CD pipeline for deploying the Springboot project. I have integrated SonarQube in my project. In my sonar-project.properties file I have mentioned the sonar.coverage.exclusions. But its not excluded properly.

below is my Project structure

Test-Service

- user-service
- async-service
- audit-service

So, I have added the sonar property file under Test-service, in that file I have mentioned the sonar coverage exclusions like below

```
sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/com/cadmium/async/business/config/*,**/com/cadmium/async/business/domain/*,**/com/cadmium/audit/business/config/*,**/com/cadmium/audit/business/domain/*,**/com/cadmium/user/business/config/*,**/com/cadmium/user/business/domain/*
```

and In gitlab-ci.yml file I have specified the sonar job like below

```
Sonar_test:
  stage: sonar
  #when: manual
  image: maven
  script:
    - mvn --batch-mode verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=sonar-url -Dsonar.login=admin  -Dsonar.password=admin -Denv="$PROFILE" -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true
```

The problem is, when I'm running the pipeline its not considering my sonar.coverage.exclusions list, So build gate getting failed because of coverage.

If I mentioned the sonar exclusion list in gitlab.yml file like below its working fine

```
Sonar_test:
  stage: sonar
  #when: manual
  image: maven
  script:
    - mvn --batch-mode verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=sonar-url -Dsonar.login=admin  -Dsonar.password=admin -Denv="$PROFILE" -Dsonar.coverage.exclusions=**/com/cadmium/async/business/config/*,**/com/cadmium/async/business/domain/*,**/com/cadmium/audit/business/config/*,**/com/cadmium/audit/business/domain/*,**/com/cadmium/user/business/config/*,**/com/cadmium/user/business/domain/* -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true
```

Why its not considering the exclusion list when I mentioned in sonar-project.properties file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a sonar sourcer says [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/not-able-to-read-sonar-project-properties-using-maven-sonar-sonar-goal/45637/2), maven projects cannot use `sonar-project.properties`.

You can define the properties directly in the `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
     ...
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/JavaClassToExclude.java</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
  </properties>
```

or via the attribute `-Dsonar.coverage.exclusions=**/JavaClassToExclude.java` in command line like you've mentioned

Comment: Good advice. My only comment is about the snippet. There is a small mistake in the snippet: the property name is `sonar.coverage.exclusions` as you pointed out correctly with the command line option.

Comment: For those using gradle, here is the syntax: `sonarqube { properties { property "sonar.coverage.exclusions", "**/JavaClassToExclude.java" } }`

Comment: Yà, correct. They both are valid properties, but for different purposes. I'm going to edit the answer to fix it, thans @dbaltor.